# Android ListView: internal top/bottom margins as part of scrollable content

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have a `ListView` which I want to look like a card.  I have a 9-patch to use as a background that achieves the raised card look.

In the likely chance it's larger than the screen, I'd want to be able to see a top margin above my card background, and when I scroll down the list, the margin should be pushed up off the screen.  When I scroll to the bottom, I should similarly see the bottom margin appear.

`ListView.addHeaderView()` and `.addFooterView()` don't cut it in my case, because those become part of backing `ListAdapter` and get drawn within the bounds of my card background.

I've seen a technique that would work - wrapping my `ListAdapter` with one that decorates each item with elements of the card background I'd want.  In this approach, each item draws a part of the card background.

However, this is less efficient than I'd like and it doesn't seem like logic that belongs in a `ListAdapter`.  Instead I'm looking for a way to extend `ListView` to add this behavior, but I find myself getting lost while trying to read the 10,000 lines (seriously) of code in `AbsListView` and `ListView`.

I think pretty much the same question was asked a year ago here, but it got no answer:
[(Android) How to fill ListView background and preserve header transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459468/android-how-to-fill-listview-background-and-preserve-header-transparency)

**EDIT**

Another way to view this problem: is there a way to make the background scroll along with the list items?  I think the answer is no - I believe the background (i.e. the `ListView` widget) is positioned fixed with respect to the screen, rather than the scrollable content within.  If I'm on the right track with this thinking, then it would appear that the `ListAdapter`-with-partial-backgrounds-per-item approach is the only viable one.